# Почему не используют LDAP?

Tags: база-данных, ldap

У меня сколько проектов, ровно столько же иерархических структур хранения. В основном, и документы и единицы аппаратуры и и пути следования все это имеет иерархическую структуру хранения. Но многочисленные разработчики предлагают использовать различные субд, вместо старого доброго ldap. Почему?

Comment: Наверное, потому, что ldap не поддерживает старый добрый SQL, да еще с join-ами, агрегациями и т.д

Answer (score 2):

SQL базы данных более распространены и более знакомы разработчикам.